# How to bind property animation values?

Tags: c#, xaml, controltemplate

```
 <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="mainGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.Width" Duration="00:00:00.5" From="40" To="100"/>
```

x:Name of the grid is mainGrid.
As you see this is the code responsible for the animation. I want something like `From="mainGrid.ActualWidth`" and `To="mainGrid.ActualWidth + 10"` But how can I bind these values to actualwidth property?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a converter. Consider the following markup sample:

```
<Grid Name="mainGrid" Width="40" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:local">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:Plus10Converter x:Key="Plus10Converter"/>    
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Button>
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="mainGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" Duration="00:00:00.5" 
                                             From="{Binding ElementName=mainGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                                             To="{Binding ElementName=mainGrid, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource Plus10Converter}}"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

and this is the code behind:

```
namespace local
{
    public class Plus10Converter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is double == false) return null;
            return (double)value + 10.0;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try as soon as possible and give you a feedback. thanks